How do I quickly convert a texture atlas into multiple 2D assets (planes)?
I want to create 2D assets using planes from a texture atlas. The image below will demonstrate the process I've been using to achieve this. After I've resized in step 3, I want to skip all future resizing since it's already been perfectly scaled to match the reference. But when I duplicate and adjust the UV map, it distorts the texture and I have to resize every new asset. Is there some way to skip this constant resizing and keep it perfectly proportioned for all future assets?
I'm also open to any other way to accomplish this goal.
In the example, there's only 4 textures which wouldn't take too long to handle the manual way. But my real projects will very often have 30+ textures that I need to turn into assets and this process becomes laborious very fast.

Below is the old example I provided. It's one possible solution that I've been told is impossible. Keeping this here for posterity:
Basically, I want to make edits in the UV editor, but I want all the transformations I make there to also happen to the object the texture is on so that the scale of the texture is preserved in the 3D viewport.
Let's say you have a plane with a texture applied. Normally, if you scale down in the UV editor, it will make the texture appear to grow on the object. Instead of this, I want the object to shrink down with my transformation in the UV editor so it looks like the texture isn't changing at all in the 3D viewport. I hope this makes sense. See diagram below.


Hello and welcome. Is there any reason for this? You might need to give more context. As far as I know this is not possible, but probably if you give some context, someone could answer with a different way to achieve your main goal

This would mean scaling the image, and not the map. I guess you could rig up something something like that in GN, but it wouldn't be in the UV editor... and you could never  transform  a coordinate system without that being the equivalent of an inverse transformation on the entity measured by it... it's kind of what coordinates are.

My conclusion is that as it stands what you want to achieve is impossible in Blender. Geometry transformations are one directional, what happens in the 3D view may or may not translate to the UV editor, but what happens in the UV editor only affetcs UVs, not geometry positions. This would only work as expected in the simplest of cases like the illustrated plane, not on complex geometry. Anyway this sounds like the XY Problem , why not use other types of texture coordinates instead?

There is a very easy solution: duplicate the object and edit the mesh only by sliding/cutting edges and delete unneeded parts so only the part you want is left. It will leave the UVs at the position and size it needs to be.

Or just cut the parts out with the knife tool and separate them.

Thank you so much that works perfectly! @MartynasŽiemys
